# Spring Security - Struts2 Integration

Tags: struts2, spring-security

I am developing a dynamic web application in Eclipse. 
I am using Struts2 as my framework along with Hibernate as my ORM.
I need to implement role based access control for which I found Spring Security to be ideal.
However, I am having difficulty integrating it to my project.

I need help integrating, for which any help/advice/tutorial would be humbly accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/) website to be quite useful for beginners dealing with web development technologies